# Can a PDA guess more than once? L = {aⁿ bⁱ aⁿ | i,n > 0 }

Tags: computability

PDA = Pushdown Automata

Let's assume I have this language:

$L = \{a^nb^ma^n | m,n \ge 1\}$

Would the first approach with one node be enough - in that case it guess twice the $\lambda$. In the second approach it's deterministic, which is fine.[image]

Comment: What a PDA can do is defined by the syntax and semantics of PDAs. If you understand the syntax of PDAs - how a PDA is defined - and its semantics - what is the language that the PDA accepts - then you already know what a PDA can and cannot do.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus After reading more than once the definitions, and solving many exercises, checking solutions, this is the first time I've approached a solution that makes the PDA guess twice. Maybe I didn't understand the solution, or the definition.

Comment: You can do everything which is allowed by the rules. In mathematics we have complete freedom under the rules of the game.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus From my understanding of the definitions, the non-deterministic approach says "if we have at least one solution", we accept it and finish. But Meaning at every step of the way it can guess whether to guess or not.

Comment: Moreover, that non-deterministic decision to guess is like an $\epsilon$ path from first to second state

Comment: What do you mean by "first approach" and "second approach"? The image contains only one PDA.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It contains two PDAs. One non-determinstic and one determinstic.

Comment: Every context-free language is accepted by some PDA with a single state and many different $\lambda$-transitions.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus And those $\lambda$ transitions can be referred as 'guesses' that the PDA can do at any given time when the PDA in that currently state that 'supports' lambda transitions?

Comment: The semantics of the PDA model are that you are always allowed to take a $\lambda$ transition (if you have the correct symbol at the top of the stack). You can think of the "decision" of whether to take such a transition or not as a guess if you wish.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If I want to refrain from the top of the stack, I can just write $\lambda$ then.

Comment: That's up to the syntax of the specific PDA model you're using, but generally speaking it's a reasonable shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with one stack.

1. Start inserting a's into the stack.
2. Stop inserting a's when we encounter the first b. Halt any operations with respect to the stack as long as we get b's.
3. Start popping stack contents immediately when the b's stop and a's start.

Comment: I've already posted a solution. I've asked something else in the thread. But thanks for the input.

Comment: The image did not load :p.